# Deleting the last element when there are only two elements in a singly linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

If there are 3 or more elements in the list, I could successfully just remove the last. But when there are two elements in the list, everytime I try to delete the last element, it also deletes the first element.

```
    node *tail = new node;
    admintemp = adminhead;

    while (admintemp->next!=NULL)
    {
        tail=admintemp;
        admintemp=admintemp->next;
    }
    if (tail)
    {
        tail->next=NULL;
    }
    delete admintemp;
```

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that it deletes the first element? And btw. you leak an instance of `node` that you use to initialise `tail`.

Comment: Displayed all the elements afterwards.

Comment: define admintemp and adminhead

Comment: How do you display them? Except for the leak, there seems to be nothing wrong in this code. So I would guess your display method is wrong.

Comment: is `node` a simple struct? Is there a destructor that could be causing this? I don't see anything clearly wrong here.

Comment: adminhead is the "head", first element. admintemp is just a temporary name, something like that.

Comment: @HanKenny The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: This fails if there is only one element in the list. 1) Change `node* tail = new node;` to `node *tail = NULL;` 2) change `if(tail){tail->next=NULL;}` to `if(tail){tail->next=NULL}else{head->next = NULL;}`

Answer (score 0):

```
  Explaination:
   With the help of temp we reach upto last node so as far as your problem                is   
concerned imagine you have two nodes only.so with temp we reach to second 
node
Now with the help of temp1 we traverse up to temp,we make temp1's next to
NULL coz now it is end.free memory of temp with help of free(temp)      





void Delete()
{
  class Node* temp,*temp1;
  temp=temp1=start;
  while(temp->next!=NULL)
{
 temp=temp->next;
}
while(temp1->next!=temp)
{
temp1=temp1->next;
}
temp1->next=NULL;
free(temp);
}
```